# Finding maximal spanning tree using Prim's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, prims-algorithm

Can we compute the maximal spanning tree by changing the algorithm to choosing the maximum vertex instead of choosing the minimum one?

I have come across the solution by negating the edges and applying the normal Prim's Minimum Spanning Tree algorithm.

Comment: If you have a minimum tree-finding implementation and can't or don't want to change it, then using negative weights is probably reasonable. But if you are implementing yourself, it's best to do what you first proposed. Prim's algorithm is greedy. Greedily seeking the maximum works just as well as greedily seeking the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Feed in to the algorithm the input graph, but with the weights negated. Nothing in Prim assumes the weights are positive. The minimum of the weights negated, is achieved by the maximum of the original weights.

Comment: "Nothing in Prim assumes the weights are positive" (But be careful with, e.g., Boost Graph Library, whose implementation does IIRC.)